# Should I add in the contract that all communication hours are billable hours?

Tags: contracts

Should I add in the contract that all communication hours (emails, answering questions) are billable hours?
Is this standard?

Comment: What industry? How many people work under you? What is the minimum charge? What have you agreed to in the past?

Comment: I'm a software developer. 0 people work under me. I don't know. It's the first job.

Comment: I suggest you do. Many clients seem to think communication is free.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **clearly** define what constitutes billable communications.

It is **not** customary for **any** business to bill customers merely because they contacted the business. In fact, it would be fairly *infuriating* if you got charged every time you contacted any business. I, personally, would *never* want a client to feel they aren't free to contact me. That seems like a roadblock to lucrative client communications.

Now, with that being posted... long "meetings" over the phone or a messenger *should* be billable hours. If you have to take an hour or two out of your day to speak with a client about progress, changes, implementation, then yes you should be invoicing for that hour or two. For some clients, this is the only ting that will prevent them being a nuance. So invoice for meetings.. don't invoice for "communication" in general. Set a limit... anything longer than X minutes becomes billable.